# Cannot use parameter PASSWORD for a Windows login in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Recently, I installed SQL Server on my machine, but I forgot the password, eventually I couldn't use SQL Server authentication with the domain user. I tried to reset the password, but I am getting an error:

> Cannot use parameter PASSWORD for a Windows login

This is the query I tried:

```
ALTER LOGIN [xxx\yyy] WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO

USE [master]
GO

ALTER LOGIN [xxx\xxx] WITH PASSWORD=N'password' MUST_CHANGE
GO
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Obviously your login is a windows account and it is windows that does the authorization for these. Sql server does not store passwords for windows accounts; there is nothing to change here. SQL Server logins will not have the form of "domain\user"

Comment: Login to your Windows machine with any account that is a member of the Administrators group and then use Local User Manager (lusrmgr.msc) to change the password on your affected account. **BE AWARE** Changing the password from another account will lose any encrypted files, stored passwords and/or personal security certificates that were attached to the account.